# SQL Query - Select Distinct COUNT of non-primary ID column

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am trying to count how many individual IDs I have in the `LogID` column of my table, which is something I should easily be able to do via

```
$sql = ("SELECT COUNT(distinct LogID) FROM qci_dmlog_data");
```

LogID is NOT my primary / unique ID column for this table, instead its a reference number which can appear more than once throughout the table. Fact is, I have 9 rows with 8 UNIQUE LogID's (the first 2 are the same) but the above code always spits out `9` as a result.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  Note that regardless of the database, your query looks correct, so you should show the calling code and explain the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code would spit out 9 is because two columns that look the same are not.  In this case, the suspect values are the rows with 446289.

I imagine that the values are not integers, because with integers "what you see is what you get".  Depending on the data type, one of two things is likely.

If the data type is a floating point representation, then one of the values might be something like 446288.999997.  The output might just be rounded to the nearest integer (for some reason).

If the data type is a string, then there are hidden characters of some sort.  This would generally fall into one of three categories:

- Spaces at the end of the string (or less likely at the beginning)
- Characters that look like numbers but are not (think "O" the letter versus "0" the number).  This gets much worse when you expand the character set.
- Unprintable characters.

Comment: Thanks for that, I checked the structure and the column values are INT(11) and neither value has any hidden characters, etc. Further, the LogID numbers have no floating points, therefore if one is subject to rounding up / down, the other one should be too and result in the same figure.

Comment: @Armitage2k . . . Could you have a tenth row that you just don't see?  Does `count(*)` also return 9?

Comment: Count(*) returns 9 as well. I checked in PHPMyAdmin and made sure to display all rows, it is 9 rows and 9 of them have unique LogIDs... -_-

Comment: Right, so I deleted the column completely and added a new one with a INT(6) structure, followed by repopulating the reference number and voila, its correct now. Not sure what caused this, but for now I am happy its ok. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Armitage2k . . . Perhaps there was some sort of uncommitted transaction, so the data you saw in the table was not the same data another process would see.  This can happen; it is not the first thing that comes to mind, though.

Answer (score -1):

Try out:

```
SELECT LogId, Count(LogId) AS count 
FROM qci_dmlog_data 
HAVING Count(LogId) = 1
GROUP BY LogId;
```

Maybe this will work better for you